# Installing VMware on MacBook - Free version

Tags: macbook-pro, vmware, windows

I need to install Windows 8 on my MacBook. So I am hoping to install VMware and then install Windows 8 on top of it.

I need to know if I need to install VMware Player or VMware Fusion? I am using this for non-commercial use so I require a free version.

Note: VMware Fusion is a licensed version, and I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VMware Player is only avaiable for Windows and Linux, not OS X. To install Windows 8 on your Mac, you will need to purchase VMware Fusion.

From [VMware Workstation Player (formerly known as Player Pro)](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html):

> VMware Player is the easiest way to run multiple operating systems at the same time on your PC.

You do have a couple of free options:

- [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a free program that will allow you to install Windows 8 alongside OS X in the same way that VMware Fusion works (you can run both OSs concurrently).
- Apple's own [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) software will allow you to install Windows in a separate partition. The downside to this is you have to reboot your computer to switch between OSs, but the upside is that you can run more graphically-intense programs (i.e. games) at native speeds.

Comment: Correction: VMWare is NOT a Windows-only application. It also supports Linux.

Comment: Nice, has it always supported Linux or is that fairly recent? Updated my answer to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: According to my experience, it has the same functionality as the Windows version.

Comment: At least it was available since version 2.0.